# Structure space of a commutative ring with unity

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading the topic for the discussion of Stone-Cech compactification but stocked at some point:
Suppose that $(R,+,.)$ is a commutative ring with unity. Let $\mathcal{M}(R)$ denotes the collection of all its maximal ideal endowed with the Stone topology (Hull-Kernel topology). For $r\in R, $ let $M(r)$ denote the collection of all maximal ideals that contains $r.$

How do I show that the set $M(r)$ is closed?

In short, how do one show that an ideal is closed in a ring?

What does it mean to define the closure of an ideal?

Comment: Presumably "closed" here means "closed in the Zariski topology," in which case this is true by definition.

Comment: No, that can't be true. This is because we have a different topology define on the structure space called the Stone topology, different from the zariski topology

Comment: Please what is the meaning of the closure of an ideal?

Comment: Any further help on this problem?

Comment: Is it true to say that M(r)=$\overline{<r>},$ where $<r>=\{ra:a\in R\}?$